# Flutter flow choice chips inside query issue

Tags: flutter, flutterflow

I have an issue with one of my FF pages. the page contains a list of topics from Firebase, under each topic there should be choice chips related to that topic, clicking on one of the chips opens a bottom sheet with the clicked related data.

i managed to create the page, and logic and click action all seem ok, but there is a problem when i click on one of the chips, the bottom sheet opens many times (by the count of the main topics) instead of one time as i click a single chip.

what i am doing wrong?

[this is the simple page structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOs9U.png)
[this is the elements of that page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Etv2.png)
[this is how the page looks like before clicking chip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUXPc.png)
[this is the sheet that opens on click over and over again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FR6JM.png)

Tried using choice chips without component, gave error that i must use a component for that chips, something with shared variable.